# Why is method not working as I thought it would?

Tags: java, methods

I am attempting to create a hangman game.  I have everything working as I want so far with the exception of one method.  This method is called `processGuess` and takes a String letter and two String arrays as parameters. The first array is an array called `spaceArray` and contains Underscores that match the length of the word being guessed (example: hello produces `[ _ , _ , _ , _ , _ ]`). The second array is called `wordArray` and contains the word the user is trying to guess.

The way I envision my method working is as follows:

1. Create an array that stores all guessed letters (`guessArray`)
2. Create a counter that keeps track of the number of guesses (`guessCounter`)
3. Use a for loop to iterate through each letter of the word and compare it with the letter the user guessed.
   a. If the letter is in the word, add the letter to the correct index of the `spaceArray`
4. Compare `spaceArray` to `wordArray`
   a. If equal, print something saying they won in x number of guesses
   b. If not equal.

   1. Print `spaceArray`
   2. Call the method that asks user to guess the next letter
   3. Call this method so that the new guessed letter is processed.

The problem is that when I recall this method, it does not contain the new letter but still contains the old letter.  I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.  This is the first time that I have tried using methods within a method.

Here is my method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner file = new Scanner(
            new File("C:/FilesForJava/ScrabbleDictionary.txt"));
    instructions();
    String[] dictionary = createDictonaryArray(file);
    String[] randomWord = getRandomWord(dictionary);
    String[] underscoreArray = showSpaces(randomWord);
    String letter = getGuesses();
    processGuess(letter, underscoreArray, randomWord);
}
public static void instructions() {     
    System.out.println("Let's play hangman!");  
    System.out.println();
}
public static String[] createDictonaryArray(Scanner inputFile) 
        throws FileNotFoundException {      
    int wordCount = 0;      
    while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
        String word = inputFile.next();
        wordCount++;                
    }
    String[] scrabbleDictionary = new String[wordCount];
    Scanner file = new Scanner(
            new File("C:/FilesForJava/ScrabbleDictionary.txt"));
    while(file.hasNext()) {         
        for(int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
            scrabbleDictionary[i] = file.next();
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return scrabbleDictionary;      
}
public static String[] getRandomWord(String[] dict) {       
    String word = dict[(int)(Math.random() * dict.length)];         
    String[] wordArray = new String[word.length()];     
    for(int i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
        wordArray[i] = word.trim().substring(0, 1);
        word = word.trim().substring(1);        
    }       
    return wordArray;
}

public static String[] showSpaces(String[] word) {
    String[] spaceArray = new String[word.length];      
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        spaceArray[i] = "_";            
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spaceArray));
    System.out.println();
    return spaceArray;
}   
public static String getGuesses() {
    Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Guess a letter: ");     
    String letter = guess.next();
    System.out.println();
    //guess.close();
    return letter;              
}
public static void processGuess(String letter, String[] spaceArray, 
        String[] wordArray) {
    int guessCounter = 0;           
    String[] guessArray = new String[spaceArray.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < spaceArray.length; i++) {
        guessCounter++;
        guessArray[i] = letter; 
        String indexLetter = wordArray[i];          
        if(indexLetter.equalsIgnoreCase(letter)) {
            spaceArray[i] = letter;                         
        }       
    }
    if(spaceArray.equals(wordArray)) {
        System.out.println("Yes! You won in " + guessCounter + "guesses!");
    }else {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spaceArray));
        getGuesses();
        processGuess(letter, spaceArray, wordArray);
    }       
}
```

Comment: 1.) what does `getGuesses()` do? 2.) I don't think you should have used recursion here.

Comment: I'd need more code - but I'm guessing you need to return your letter from `getGuesses` and pass it in to `processGuess` in place of the `letter` parameter.

Comment: @Zhuinden I have added the rest of my code.

Comment: @StevenHansen I have added the rest of my code

Comment: Did you try with step by step debugging in some IDE?

Comment: @Neo Yes, I did debug it. That is why I knew that the method wasn't processing the new letter and instead was reprocessing the old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the new guess into your `processGuess` method.  Try something like this:

```
else {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spaceArray));
    String newLetter = getGuesses();
    processGuess(newLetter, spaceArray, wordArray);
}
```

Comment: Ah I understand now and see where I was going wrong.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You don't need to create a new String to pass, you can either just set letter to what getGuesses returns, or even just call the method like this: processGuess(getGuesses(), spaceArray, wordArray) but thats nitpicky, otherwise exactly right

Answer (score 1):

I think this method is trying to do too much.  It's strange for it to read new input and call itself recursively -- I would have expected its caller to use a loop to solicit guesses from the player and call this method (which would not recurse) instead.  The method might indicate by a return value whether the user had won.

Additionally, the code seems overly complex.  For instance, what's the point of `guessArray`, which you instantiate and initialize but never use for anything?

Furthermore, it's strange that you use arrays of Strings instead of arrays of chars, since all your Strings seem to contain a single character each.  (That might actually be appropriate if you are looking to accommodate surrogate pairs, but such a consideration seems a little out of character for the level of the task.)

In any event, the reason the recursive calls to your method see only the first letter guessed is that that's what you pass to them.  The `getGuesses()` method does nothing to modify the local `letter` variable (nor can it do), and the method itself just passes along whatever was passed to it.

Comment: I am self teaching myself and have nothing to go by except for the book I am using so I'm sure there are much better ways of designing what I am trying to do. I will follow your suggestions and rework my methods.  I created the guessArray because I will eventually show the user an array of the letters he/she has used.  I used String arrays just because I am more familiar with dealing with Strings than I am chars.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You've written the method as a recursive method (probably not the best way to do it).  The issue is that when a recursive method declares a local variable, *each* invocation of the recursive method **has its own copy of the local variables**.

Thus you call `processGuess`, which creates a `guessArray`.  Then `processGuess` calls itself again, which has its own `guessArray`, and after this happens a few times, you'll have a stack that looks something like:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
+  processGuess#1                                        +
+    local variables: guessCounter#1, guessArray#1, i#1  +
+--------------------------------------------------------+ --> calls:
+  processGuess#2                                        +
+    local variables: guessCounter#2, guessArray#2, i#2  +
+--------------------------------------------------------+ --> which calls:
+  processGuess#3                                        +
+    local variables: guessCounter#3, guessArray#3, i#3  +
+--------------------------------------------------------+ --> which calls:
+  processGuess#4                                        +
+    local variables: guessCounter#4, guessArray#4, i#4  +
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

When `processGuess#4` modifies `guessArray`, it changes `guessArray#4`.  But that has **no** effect on `guessArray#3`, `guessArray#2`, or `guessArray#1`.  All of these are separate local variables, and they are references that refer to four different objects.  Thus, when `processGuess#4`, `processGuess#3`, and `processGuess#2` all return, the changes they've made to their own `guessArray`'s are lost, and `processGuess#1` will see only the changes that it, itself, has made to its own `guessArray`.

As I said, I wouldn't use recursion for this particular problem.  But it's definitely a problem in other cases where recursion *is* the right way to do things.  The solutions are: (1) declare the variable or object *outside* the recursive method, as an instance field in the object--then they will all be accessing the same variable; or (2) add a parameter to the recursive method so that the recursive invocations can share a reference to the same object.

[Note: The `#1`, `#2` numbers I added are just to help explain things; they aren't part of any language syntax or anything like that.]

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I will take yours and others comments to heart and rework my design.

Comment: guessArray is eventually going to help the user keep track of the letters guessed. I will display it after every guess.  I just didn't implement it yet.

Comment: @comfortablyNumb OK.  If that's true, you probably will not want to have every recursive invocation create a new one (assuming you continue to use recursion).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you might have a couple of problems.

First, recursion is a very poor choice for this method, I think what you're looking for is a while loop where the condition changes when the strings are equal. Using recursion here needlessly increases the size of the stack as you call more and more methods, but never return from them.

Now as to your question, in the code you gave us, the variable letter never gets changed. I assume that get guesses returns a string? If thats true then you need to set letter equal to it.

I would also like to suggest that you use a char instead of a string.

```
public static void processGuess(String letter, String[] spaceArray,
                                String[] wordArray) {
  while(true) {
    int guessCounter = 0;
    String[] guessArray = new String[spaceArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < spaceArray.length; i++) {
        guessCounter++;
        guessArray[i] = letter;
        String indexLetter = wordArray[i];
        if (indexLetter.equalsIgnoreCase(letter)) {
            spaceArray[i] = letter;
        }
    }
    if (spaceArray.equals(wordArray)) {
        System.out.println("Yes! You won in " + guessCounter + "guesses!");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spaceArray));
        letter = getGuesses();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jared.  You and the others have given me a lot of pointers.  I will go back and rework the whole program.